# angular form, dont work reset method dont work

Tags: angular

i have a mat-tab in html and in each tab a form :

```
<mat-tab label="caption">
          <div><div style="float: right;width: 40%;">
                <form class = "tp-form" #captionf="ngForm">
                  <!-- ---------------- -->
                      <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width">
                        <input #caption matInput type=text placeholder = "caption" value = "" name="caption" >
                      </mat-form-field>
                  <br>
                  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type=button (click)="insert_data(caption.value)">add record</button>
                </form>
         </div>
```

in ts in order write this:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
...
  @ViewChild('captionf') captionF:NgForm;
...
insert_data(caption){
           this.DbSrvConnService.post_data("item_create",{caption}).subscribe(
            (res) => {
              this.captionF.reset();
            },
            (error) => {console.log(error)}
            );
   }
```

it work in addnig record,but reset method not work in my form.pls help

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-within-a-form

Comment: `resetForm()` you need this method to clear form https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n6xexk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i do not want to add reset button,i want to reset form after (res)=> in ts code

Comment: @mahdi.gh I have updated link. after 3 second text will be cleared. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n6xexk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this.captionF.resetForm() instead of this.captionF.reset();